# undefined reference to Class::Class() and Class::function()

Tags: c++, header-files, undefined-reference

I'm trying to use multiple files for the first time in C++. Here are the files I wrote.

File #1: Box.hpp

```
#ifndef BOX_HPP
#define BOX_HPP

class Box
{
    private:
        int length;
        int width;
        int height;
    
        Box() {}

    public:
        Box(int _length, int _width, int _height);

        void set_dimensions(int _length, int _width, int _height);
        int volume();
 };

 #endif
```

File #2: Box.cpp

```
#include "Box.hpp"

Box::Box(int _length, int _width, int _height)
{
    set_dimensions(_length, _width, _height);
}

void Box::set_dimensions(int _length, int _width, int _height)
{
    length = _length;
    width = _width;
    height = _height;
}

int Box::volume()
{
    return length*width*height;
}
```

File #3: main.cpp

```
#include "Box.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Box box1 = Box(1,2,3);
    std::cout << box1.volume() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run main.cpp I get the following errors:

> undefined reference to 'Box::Box(int, int, int)'
>
> undefined reference to 'Box::volume()'

I cannot figure out why.

Comment: How are you building the program? Are you linking *both* source files?

Comment: Maybe this will help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173217/c-calling-a-function-from-another-class

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile using both files like:

```
$ g++ main.cpp Box.cpp
```

I think You are compiling like this:

```
$ g++ main.cpp
```